# How to export multiple artwork without the number of artwork not printed? (Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, png

Is there a way to export in illustrator but the number of artwork is not printed in the name as well?

Let's say I have two artboard and I want each artboard to save in different folder.
Every time I export the page number shows artboard-01 and artboard-02.
I don't want to have the "01" and "02" as it is time consuming to manually rename them if there are a lot of artboard I need to rename them.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How does photoshop know that the mane is different then? Anyway just go to your shell and cut the name shorter with rename and glob seems easy enough

Comment: There are also OS tools for both MacOS and Windows to rename files... so it only takes a second there.

Comment: A friend told me you can try use Adobe Bridge to rename multiple files by using string substitute